# error happens when nodejs tries to exec a shell script

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell

code here:

```
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('sh  ~/public/markdoc/depoly.sh', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    sys.puts(stdout);
    if (error != null) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

gives the error:

```
{ [Error: Command failed: sh: /home/users/zhangxuan06/public/markdoc/depoly.sh: No such file or directory
] killed: false, code: 127, signal: null }
```

Can someone tell me why?
Big Thx~

Comment: Isn't the error message descriptive enough by itself?

Comment: 1) ignore error message, ask question on SO. 2) ??? 3) profit.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `depoly`, but you probably meant `deploy`.